# Atomically check-and-set using Elixir Ecto Repo?

Tags: elixir, ecto

How do I atomically check-and-set something in Ecto Repo? I want to make sure no other process changed any part of the struct in parallel, even if the two writes are not-overlapping and read the same data.

For example,

```
Process A:
1. read {x=3, y=5}
2. update {x=100+3+5} 
Process B:
1. read {x=3, y=5}
2. update {y=200+3+5}
```

Here at least one of the processes (and preferably exactly one) should fail and retry, since they both depend on both values, even if they only change one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ecto.Changeset.optimistic_lock/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#optimistic_lock/3) does exactly what you want. It will require a migration to the table in question (adds a `version` field or whatever you want to call it).

I could give you an example but I would just be copying and pasting from the docs. They describe it perfectly.